# Text is not appearing on QGraphicsView in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt4, qgraphicsview

I am having a `QGraphicsView` which contains some `QGraphicsItem`. I want to put name on each `QGraphicsItem`. For that I have created class myText which is inheriting `QGraphicsTextItem`.
But the issue is name is not appearing on `QGraphicsItem`.
Here is the code:

myText.h

```
class myText: public QGraphicsTextItem
{
public:
    explicit myText(QString);
    void DrawText(int,int);
    void paint (QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget);
}
```

myText.cpp

```
myText::myText(QString text): QGraphicsTextItem(text)
{}

myText::myText()
{}

void myText::DrawText(int firstPos,int secondPos)
{
    this->setPos(firstPos,secondPos);
}

 void myText::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
{
    Q_UNUSED(painter);
    Q_UNUSED(option);
    Q_UNUSED(widget);
    qDebug()<<"Painter for text called ";
}
```

myView.cpp

```
void myView::DrawDesign()
{
    QString s = "Line 1";
    myText* text = new myText(s);
    text->DrawText(co-ordinates of text);
    scene->addItem(static_cast<QGraphicsTextItem*>(text));
}
```

Here, name text is not appearing on any `QGraphicsItem`. Why is this happening ?

If I use following code then text appears but `paint()` does not work.

```
QGraphicsTextItem *name = new QGraphicsTextItem(s);
name->setPos( co-ordinates for text );
scene->addItem(name);
```

Comment: `myText::paint` doesn't paint anything, so why are you surprised? And what is wrong with `QGraphicsTextItem` that you think it is a good idea to alter its behavior?

Comment: The name of `myText::DrawText` lies! Same `myView::DrawText`.  Do not write code which claims to do something and does something completely different.

Comment: @MarekR  Atleast now, `paint()` is not painting anything. Later on I want to write code for selection in `paint()`. ( want to change Qt's default selection feature, i.e. dashed rectangular around object) Currently I was checking whether `paint()` is working now or not. It is working.  Before this I was using `QGraphicsTextItem *name = new QGraphicsTextItem(s);` and `paint()` was not getting called. So I chnaged this way.

Comment: @MarekR Sorry I have changed the name. Sorry once again !